# Why do I get a Format Exception when comparing int and float values?

Tags: c#, parsing, formatexception

I don't know why but I am getting a `FormatException` when comparing two values. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I already tried to make both values float, yet the same exception...

```
float label1 = float.Parse(label15.Text);
int box1 = int.Parse(textBox23.Text);

if (label1 <= box1)
{
    //Do things"
}
```

Comment: Start from [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging).

Comment: You're not getting a format exception when comparing int and float values. You're getting a format exception when the string in `label15` is not parseable as a number. What does it say about your attention to detail that a complete stranger on the internet knows more than you about which line in your code is throwing an exception?

Comment: what value are you entering in that textbox?

Comment: But why is the label not parseable? Its just a String for example 2,5? Or is it because of the comma and it has to be a point?

Comment: Why you enter 2,5 in the textbox. When you parse the string to number, the parse will be performed based on the current culture of the machine on which code is running. In your case it looks like the number is being parsed with format where `dot` is used as decimal separator. That's why you are seeing the error. If you expect that number to be parsed with specific format you need to provide appropriate culture info. `float.Parse("2.2", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("culturename")`

Comment: Both of your `Parse` statements are parsing the same textbox.  Is that intended?  If the textbox contains a decimal point, then `int.Parse` will fail because integers cannot have a decimal point.  Try using the various `TryParse` methods instead.  That will prevent an exception from being thrown and you can handle the cases where invalid input is given.

Comment: Sorry, dont know how this could happend, it was not intended. I changed the Question. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got yourself in a corner without using proper exception handling.

```
    float label1 = float.Parse(label15.Text);  //problem 1
    int box1 = int.Parse(label15.Text);  //problem 2

    if (label1 <= box1)  //problem 3
    {
    //Do things"
    }
```

Problems 1 and 2 are that you aren't ensuring your UI is giving you values that you can parse.  That will throw exceptions.  Problem 3 is that since you don't know if your parsing was successful, you don't know if you can even make the comparison.   Try `TryParse()`.

```
    float label1 = 0;

                int box1 = 0;

                if(float.TryParse(label15.Text, out label1)
                    &&  int.TryParse(label15.Text, out box1))
                {
                   if (label1 <= box1)
                   {
                   //Do things"
                   }
                }
```

The `TryParse()` function populates your existing variables as `out` parameters, but returns a `bool`.  This returns as `false` if the parse fails, and allows the code to continue.  By making these succeeding an `if` condition, we sidestep errors entirely.

You can also always wrap your code in a `try-catch block` to determine the cause of any exception and generate output, but you never want that to manage your logical flow.  You'd use that to troubleshoot this problem, and what I posted as a possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

[FormatException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The exception that is thrown when the format of an argument is
>   invalid, or when a composite format string is not well formed.

the error is because whatever the value of `label15` / `textBox23` is, it is not a valid number.

use [`float.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) respectively as they don't throw exceptions:

```
float label1;
if(label15.Text, out label1){
  // do something
}

int box1;
if(textBox23.Text, out box1){
   // do something
}
```

though, you'll still need to ensure that `label15` / `textBox23` is a parsable value, otherwise control will not go inside the `if` statements.

Answer (score 1):

The [float.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bh4863by(v=vs.110).aspx) method can take a second parameter.

<sub>Assuming you are looking for German number parsing based on your profile.</sub>

So if you want to parse German number formats, make sure the method knows that (because by US standards, "2,5" is not a floating point number... there's not even a *point* to start with).

In theory, your `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` should already be what you need. In case it's not, you can create a culture you need:

This should work fine:

```
float f = float.Parse("2,5", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE"))
```

Keep in mind that despite your best efforts, people might still just enter garbage in your textbox, so you should keep an eye out for [TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0xh24xh4(v=vs.110).aspx) as mentioned in the other answers. But even there: watch out for the correct culture to parse your numbers.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question and also thank you for correcting my question, next time I will do better! Danke :)